# Exporting to Excel using ClosedXML.Excel and making a header row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, export-to-excel

Below is a snippet of a function I am using to successfully export a GridView to Excel and this code merges a range of cells, and formats the text. Now I would also like to make this header row appear on every print page should a user elect to print the worksheet. I'm thinking that this must be a configurable item, so what would be the syntax for this please?

```
    Dim xlDoc As New XLWorkbook()
    xlDoc.AddWorksheet("Export")
    Dim xlWS As IXLWorksheet = xlDoc.Worksheets(0)
    xlWS.Row(1).Cell(1).Value = "some text"
    xlWS.Row(1).Cell(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(255, 255, 102)
    xlWS.Row(1).Cell(1).Style.Font.Bold = True
    xlWS.Range("A1", "G1").Merge()
    xlWS.Range("A1", "G1").Style.Border.OutsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin
    xlWS.Range("A2", "G2").SetAutoFilter()
```

Comment: Where is your error?

Comment: @Jelly Thank you for your response, I've shelved this for the time being and hope to revisit it imminently!